# Quick way to type text on desktop and then transfer to mobile

Tags: note-taking, mobile

Question best understood from scenario:

- I'm working at the hospital where there are multiple workstations but I'm constantly on the move so I'm not logged in to my personal accounts
- Sometimes I need to throw a short email or personal note but typing on mobile is too slow
- I'd want to open browser on a shared workstation and type text into some textfield and push it instantly to mobile to use it there

I can NOT use services requiring login (on desktop side at least) since that's 1) an extra, time requiring step 2) security issue eg if I forget to logout from shared workstation

One example of implementation would be online notepad which creates random session with a short url which I then open in browser on mobile and  copy & paste. None of the online notepads I've found are updated realtime on mobile site.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you self-host or does it have to be a hosted service?

Comment: Make typing easier on the mobile device by getting a small Bluetooth portable keyboard or recording a voice dictation for later typing?

Comment: Using [Trello](https://trello.com) is an option. Unless you are working with HIPAA info.

Comment: *2) security issue eg if I forget to logout from shared workstation* I'd said not logging in is a much larger security issue. If you can use, so can anyone.

Comment: I could self-host and even code it but I want to check first for ready solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Host your own website and add a "contact us" page to it, and have the "contact us" page send an email to your phone.

If you don't care about design or having a website this will end up being quite cheap.

You could construct such a form that sends an email using Google Drive Spreadsheet form's feature too. Just make sure the form is publicly available and memorise it's public URL, or use a URL shortening service and memorise that URL.

Comment: CMS such as Wordpress or Drupal host free websites somewhere, so you could just build on one of those and use an URL shortner to get to it superfast.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use pastebin.com, but that isn't mobile friendly, so after a quick google search, I found [shrib](https://shrib.com), which looks like it fits your description of a simple online notepad with a unique URL.

The content seemed to sync well between mobile and desktop with my testing (note, I used 2 different mobile browsers, with one set to request desktop site).

If needed you can set your own URL, instead of the unique one created for you.